# How can I interpolate a numpy array so that it becomes a certain length?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, interpolation

I have three numpy arrays each with different lengths:

`A.shape` = (3401,)
`B.shape` = (2200,)
`C.shape` = (4103,)

I would like to average the three arrays to produce a new array with size of the largest array (in this case `C`):

`D.shape` = (4103,)

Problem is, I don't think I can do this without adding "fake" data to `A` and `B`, by interpolation.

1. How can I perform interpolation on the first two numpy arrays so that they are of the same length as array `C`?
2. Do I even need to interpolate here?

Comment: what do you mean by `I would like to average the three arrays to produce a new array with size of the largest array` does that mean `(A[i]+B[i]+C[i])/3` for each `i`? And if so, what should be the value of `A[3400]+b[3400]+C[3400]`? What of `A[4100]+B[4100]+C[4100]`??

Comment: @Onyambu Yes that is what I meant, the value would be `D[3400]` and `D[4100]`, respectively. Does that not make sense?

Comment: how would the value be `D[3400]` Do you just ignore `A[3400`]??

Comment: @Onyambu Not sure I follow

Comment: `A[3400]` has a value `B[3400]` does not exist since b`B` has length 2200, `C[3400]` has a value, now how do I combine all these to get `D[3400]`??

Comment: @Onyambu That is the basis of my question, how do I interpolate the data in the shorter arrays so that they have the same length as the longest array. Then when they're the same I can find the average.

Comment: And my question is not about interpolation. My question is the result you need. let me give you an example. if `A[3400] = 10` and `C[3400]=5`, what should be `D[3400]`? should it be `none` since we dont know `B[3400]` or should it be `7.5` the mean of `10` and `5`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest option is to do the following:

```
D = np.concatenate([np.average([A[:2200], B, C[:2200]], axis=0),
                    np.average([A[2200:3401], C[2200:3401]], axis=0),
                    C[3401:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind is [zoom](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.zoom.html) from `scipy`:

> The array is zoomed using spline interpolation of the requested order.

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage import zoom

A = np.random.rand(3401)
B = np.random.rand(2200)
C = np.ones(4103)

for arr in [A, B]:
    zoom_rate = C.shape[0] / arr.shape[0]
    arr = zoom(arr, zoom_rate)
    print(arr.shape)
```

**Output:**

```sh
(4103,)
(4103,)
```